# Why same lists doesn't point the same address?

Tags: python

Someone said to me *Everything in python is an object*. Like the example below, python just points to the same address for the same value.

```py
a = 1
b = 1
print(id(a), id(b)) # Same!
print(a is b) # True
```

But this rule seems like not being applied a list.

```py
a = [1]
b = [1]
print(id(a), id(b)) # !=
print(a is b) # False
```

I tested this for a Tuple, but it also didn't work. So I guess it's not about whether they are mutables or not. Why does this happen?

Comment: integers from -5 to 256 are interned in CPython. see e.g. here: https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming/integer-interning.htm

Comment: See [`is` operator behaves unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), [is there a difference between `==` and `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is), ...etc.

Comment: see also here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Comment: Keep in mind that we need ways to have lists that have the same elements but are different. Imagine we had only one empty list and if we created three and added elements to one, the other two would have the same elements. That problem can’t happen with immutable datatypes since they do not change. When you add ints  you get a new one. Rather than a mutated version of the old int.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist who did close the question? The question also happens in the case of string. Moreover, the sentence "Everything in python is an object" isn't correct when both a and b are larger than 255 since they have to indicate the same 'object'.

Comment: Please dudes, read the lines. The question is about "Everything of python is an object".

Comment: @user2640045 you mentioned *That problem can’t happen with immutable datatypes since they do not change.*, then why two tuple doesn't have the same address?

Comment: @InhyeokYoo I don't see how "everything is an object" is related to things having the same address. By __that problem__ I am talking about the problem with mutable datatypes I mentioned right before it.

Comment: everything in python is an object. but CPython chooses to intern some of them (i.e. make them behave like singletons [which still are objects]). small integers and short strings are examples.